# Reproducible example and dput error

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to reproduce a data frame and `dput` is not cooperating.

`dput` command :

```
dput(head(data, 10))
```

`dput` output :

```
structure(list(lexptot = c(8.28377505197124, 9.1595012302023, 
8.14707583238833, 9.86330744180814, 8.21391453619232, 8.92372556833205, 
7.77219149815994, 8.58202430280175, 8.34096828565733, 10.1133857229336
), year = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), dfmfdyr = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), dfmfd98 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), nh = c(11054L, 11054L, 11061L, 11061L, 11081L, 11081L, 
11101L, 11101L, 12021L, 12021L)), .Names = c("lexptot", "year", 
"dfmfdyr", "dfmfd98", "nh"), vars = list(nh), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
0:1, 2:3, 4:5, 6:7, 8:9), group_sizes = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(nh = c(11054L, 
11061L, 11081L, 11101L, 12021L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .Names = "nh", vars = list(nh)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Error :

```
Error in structure(list(lexptot = c(8.28377505197124, 9.1595012302023,  : 
  object 'nh' not found
```

Why is this happening right from a dput command?

Edit :

Relevant posts, but suggestions did not work.

[Why does this dplyr dput not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151796/why-does-this-dplyr-dput-not-work)

Edit 2 :

It appears because one of my variables is a `group` object, dput cannot reproduce this.  The solution is to use `ungroup(data)` then rerun dput and all works.

Comment: I've added the dplyr tag, since that is probably the root of your problem. Can't help you further since I don't use dplyr.

Comment: @Roland why would this be a dplyr problem?

Comment: You normally wouldn't have this problem if you had a "normal" data.frame. But you habe a `grouped_df` and that's very likely related. I see `vars = list(nh)` in there and that's a reference to another object which is normally not part of `dput` output.

Comment: The spaces are due to RStudio's auto-indentation coupled with unfortunate placements of line breaks (lots of mid-vector breaks, very few between-vector breaks). In the menu Tools/Global Options/Code Editing you can turn off "auto-indent after paste" if you'd like.

Comment: I'm removing the RStudio part of the question (and tag) because it's completely independent of the error. If you want more info on that, ask a separate question.

Comment: For a reproducible example, `dput(group_by(mtcars, cyl))` has the same issue. Might need to be reported as a `dplyr` issue.

Comment: You can't `dput` objects that are/contain references to other objects. That's a price you pay for performance.

Comment: Or use `dump(list = "variable_name", file = stdout())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was one of the variable objects was a `group` and therefore, `dput()` couldn't recognize this.  The solution was to `ungroup()` the data.

```
ungroup(data)
dput(head(data, 10))
```

New Data.frame :

```
structure(list(lexptot = c(8.28377505197124, 9.1595012302023, 
8.14707583238833, 9.86330744180814, 8.21391453619232, 8.92372556833205, 
7.77219149815994, 8.58202430280175, 8.34096828565733, 10.1133857229336
), year = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), dfmfd98 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), dfmfd = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("lexptot", "year", "dfmfd98", "dfmfd"
), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: I was recently pointed to this answer, but I had to do `dput(ungroup(data))`. Should this be edited?

Comment: @raphael that I'd another alternative.  The problem is the 'group' variables in the data frame.  Either way should work.