# problems in draw a bar chart with ggplot2 by using facet_grid function

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

my code about drawing bar chart is here

```
library(ggplot2)

fig_num <- ggplot(data=branch.fig, aes(y=branch.fig$num, x=branch.fig$film.type, fill = branch.fig$film.type)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", width = 0.3, colour = "gray35") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +  
  facet_grid(branch.type~.) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=branch.fig$num, ymax=branch.fig$num +branch.fig$SE), position="dodge", width=0.1, col = "gray40") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "Film Type",y = "Branch Number") + 
  ggtitle("DAS = 54") + coord_flip()
fig_num
```

The result I want to have should be like this,

[image]

but what I get is like this, the R combine part of the data, I don't know why would appear this, it's really a big problem for me to solve, sincerely looking for your help,thanks a lot!

[image]

following is dataset

```
dput(subset(branch.fig))
structure(list(film.type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("black", "ck", "dark-gray", 
"green", "red", "white"), class = "factor"), branch.type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", 
"V"), class = "factor"), num = c(14.6666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
14, 2.66666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 2, 14.6666666666667, 
2.66666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 20.3333333333333, 
1.66666666666667), SE = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
1.15470053837925, 0.333333333333333, 0.881917103688197, 0, 0.881917103688197, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
0.666666666666667), n = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("film.type", "branch.type", "num", "SE", 
"n"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = list(film.type), drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:1, 2:3, 4:5, 6:7, 8:9, 10:11), group_sizes = c(2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
 film.type = structure(1:6, .Label = c("black", "ck", "dark-gray", 
   "green", "red", "white"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame", vars = list(film.type), drop = TRUE, .Names = 
"film.type"))
```

Comment: Please provide your data in a [reproducible form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Do not link screenshot of your data, as that would require others to transcribe them before helping with your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding, I've edited my question to copy the dataset in it~

Comment: Unfortunately, the `dput` output doesn't work correctly because `dplyr` and `dput` don't entirely get along. Try posting the output of `dput(ungroup(branch.fig))` (from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039553/reproducible-example-and-dput-error)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code.
1. Your `dput` generated an error. The command below generates the data.
2. The data frame is named in `data=branch.fig`. No need to name it again as part of `aes()`.
3. There is no dodging in this chart, so drop the `dodge` commands in both `geom_bar` and `geom_errorbar`.
4. As far as I can see there is no `colors` object. I've put in some colours for the manual colour scale.

```
# Data
branch.fig = structure(list(film.type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("black", "ck", "dark-gray", 
"green", "red", "white"), class = "factor"), branch.type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", 
"V"), class = "factor"), num = c(14.6666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
14, 2.66666666666667, 15.3333333333333, 2, 14.6666666666667, 
2.66666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 20.3333333333333, 
1.66666666666667), SE = c(0.333333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 
1.15470053837925, 0.333333333333333, 0.881917103688197, 0, 0.881917103688197, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
0.666666666666667), n = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("film.type", "branch.type", "num", "SE", 
"n"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")


library(ggplot2)

# Plot
fig_num = ggplot(data = branch.fig, aes(y = num, x = film.type, fill = film.type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.3, colour = "gray35") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "orange", "grey", "green", "red", "white")) +  
  facet_grid(branch.type ~ .) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = num, ymax = num + SE), width = 0.1, col = "gray40") + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "Film Type", y = "Branch Number") + 
  ggtitle("DAS = 54") + coord_flip()

fig_num
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!!!! The problem maybe because I repeated the data frame in my code, the figure come back when I changed the code in aes()~