# Summing Contingency Tables in R with first column as character

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, contingency

My sales dataset includes 3 columns:  Countries, Sales Type/Method, Total Quarterly Revenue.  Here's a display of the first few rows for a better idea:

```
   Retailer.country Order.method.type    Qtr.Rev
         <fctr>            <fctr>      <dbl>
 1        Australia            E-mail  171407.28
 2        Australia       Sales visit 2013909.18
 3        Australia           Special  158795.34
 4        Australia         Telephone 2289201.87
 5        Australia               Web 1738303.59
 6          Austria       Sales visit   66926.18
 7          Austria         Telephone 1671887.40
 8          Austria               Web 7050164.50
 9          Belgium       Sales visit 1655507.05
10          Belgium               Web 6222440.26
etc.........
```

Here's the dput of this data:

```
    structure(list(Retailer.country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), .Label = c("Australia", "Austria", 
"Belgium", "Brazil", "Canada", "China", "Denmark", "Finland", 
"France", "Germany", "Italy", "Japan", "Korea", "Mexico", 
"Netherlands", 
"Singapore", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "United Kingdom", 
"United States"), class = "factor"), Order.method.type = 
structure(c(1L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 
6L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = 
c("E-mail", 
"Fax", "Mail", "Sales visit", "Special", "Telephone", "Web"), class = 
"factor"), 
    Qtr.Rev = c(171407.28, 2013909.18, 158795.34, 2289201.87, 
    1738303.59, 66926.18, 1671887.4, 7050164.5, 1655507.05, 
    6222440.26, 
    7746789.52, 6864270.12, 195549.5, 450628.79, 12376528.53, 
    415128.31, 1453194.14, 2735416.3, 15777880.11, 413978.16, 
    3776833.13, 308638.6, 12328172.97, 709194.65, 1304167.86, 
    5897377.14, 11048160.97, 1546079.43, 1247170.05, 2373591.15, 
    12102240.99, 2461322.51, 165800.42, 1397604.56, 198705.05, 
    7413833.64, 2662351.94, 289704.5, 680467.87, 87186.72, 343708.86, 
    1802166.73, 16990817.52, 2821127.32, 431860.34, 10144353.75, 
    5063353.42, 1725508.54, 3571760.87, 593828.88, 1074860.66, 
    2981026.86, 5254137.56, 469627.61, 908725.05, 1625096.56, 
    9677070.09, 88788.41, 337710.73, 254360.21, 7835117.44, 
    1292812.39, 
    4818848.86, 217936.39, 792168.42, 790344.28, 109161.04, 
    4565896.64, 
    697619.35, 264500.2, 189218.02, 2022968.96, 13756025.4, 
    1357389.56, 
    2352483.29, 2842600.85, 685752.21, 13437403.28, 29573813.7
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-79L), .Names = c("Retailer.country", "Order.method.type", "Qtr.Rev"
))
```

I'm creating a contingency table in R that shows the quarterly revenue generated by each sales method for each country.  The final output should look similar to this:

```
Retailer.country     E-mail        Fax      Mail Sales visit   Special  Telephone       Web  TOTAL.cn
1         Australia   171407.3       0.00       0.0  2013909.18  158795.3  2289201.9   1738304   6371617
2           Austria        0.0       0.00       0.0    66926.18       0.0  1671887.4   7050164   8788978
3           Belgium        0.0       0.00       0.0  1655507.05       0.0        0.0   6222440   7877947
4            Brazil        0.0       0.00       0.0        0.00       0.0        0.0   7746790   7746790
5            Canada  6864270.1  195549.50       0.0   450628.79       0.0        0.0  12376529  19886977
6             China        0.0  415128.31       0.0  1453194.14       0.0  2735416.3  15777880  20381619
7           Denmark        0.0       0.00       0.0   413978.16       
...
20   United Kingdom   697619.3  264500.20       0.0   189218.02       0.0  2022969.0  13756025  16930332
21    United States        0.0 1357389.56 2352483.3  2842600.85  685752.2 13437403.3  29573814  50249443
22       TOTAL.type 15695863.0 4767448.43 5692692.6 23233800.42 4811539.3 35257926.7 203769190 293228461
```

The cast() function from the reshape library gets most of the job done, and only leaves the summary column and row for all values to be computed.

```
cast(sales.by.country, Retailer.country ~ Order.method.type, 
fill=0) -> sales.by.country
```

Summing the rows into a new column named "TOTAL.cn" is pretty simple:

```
sales.by.country$TOTAL.cn <- rowSums(sales.by.country[,c(2:8)])
```

But summing the columns become a major headache, because the first component of that last row must either be a factor or character.  I converted the first column "Retailer.country" to the character type, because it really serves as nothing more than a visual label.

After fussing around with several functions, this is the best code I was able to create to achieve the intended row summation:

```
# Sum the numeric columns, which is everything *except* column 1
total.by.ordertype <- (colSums(sales.by.country[,-1]))

# Create the Total by Order row
total.by.ordertype.row <- list("TOTAL.type", total.by.ordertype[1], 
total.by.ordertype[2], total.by.ordertype[3], total.by.ordertype[4], 
total.by.ordertype[5], total.by.ordertype[6], total.by.ordertype[7], 
total.by.ordertype[8])

# Add the Total by Order row to the bottom of the table
sales.by.country[22, ] <- total.by.ordertype.row
```

It works and maintains the proper data types among all columns... BUT I figure there has to be a more efficient way, perhaps by using the apply family of functions, something from dplyr, etc. Maybe the only way is to write my own function?

For example, future datasets may have 50+ different sales methods.  When creating the list for the "Total by Order" row (above), I had to call out every single cell within the vector, separated by commas, in order to successfully add this to my existing table. Other efforts converted the data types of all the other columns to characters, which messes everything up.

I don't mind copying/pasting "total.by.ordertype" 8 times so much. But what happens when I'm dealing with 50-100 order types?  Is there a cleaner method to reproduce any of this?

Thank you!

Comment: how about `rbind(sales.by.country, data.frame(Retailer.country="total", t(total.by.ordertype)))`

Comment: @user20650 Good suggestion, thanks! That method did require re-naming the columns for the total.by.ordertype data, but this does work and prevents the copy/paste repetition of building the list: `data.frame(Retailer.country="Total.type", t(total.by.ordertype)) -> tf`
`names(tf)[2:9] <- names(sales.by.country)[2:9]`
`rbind(sales.by.country, tf) -> final.sales.by.country`
Maintains the correct data types as well.

Comment: RVD, colsums retains the names, so if you can add your original three column data to your question using `dput(yourdata)` we can see why that is not happening.

Comment: @user20650 Ok, added above.

Comment: @RVD Your `dput ` dataset is problematic. When I ran the code, the console shows this error message: `Error in structure(list(Retailer.country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  object 'Retailer.country' not found`

Comment: @ycw Ah.. I think I may know why that's happening. That "original" 3-column data isn't a typical data frame.  It has actually been grouped via dplyr.  My script runs the following on a dataset with over 8,600 observations: `sd %>% group_by(Retailer.country, Order.method.type) %>% 
  summarize(Qtr.Rev=sum(Revenue)) -> sd` This returns the data I've posted at the top of the question with only 79 observations. I'm guessing I can ungroup it and run dput, but that's going to create a massive list of output. Do you know of an easier way?

Comment: @RVD Not sure what you are talking about. You posted some codes from dput. I copied and pasted those in my R console, and then it is not working. The purpose of dput is to share data. If it is not working, no one can work on your dataset. It thus difficult to determine what happened when the proposed solution cannot work.

Comment: @ycw Right. When I attempted to recreate the data frame with the dput output on my own machine, I was seeing the same error as you. The error we're both getting is similar to the one discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039553/reproducible-example-and-dput-error  In other words, the original 3 column dataset I posted is a grouped object. I just used ungroup() on that object, ran dput on it again, and have some new output. I'll edit the dput I posted in the original question. It worked for me this time. Please let me know if it's working for you as well.

Comment: @RVD Your updated dput works now. I will update my answer based on the dataset you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cast()` function from the `reshape` library can do the whole job. With the parameter `margin = TRUE`, all row and column totals will be computed:

```
reshape::cast(sales.by.country, Retailer.country ~ Order.method.type, fun.aggregate = sum, 
     fill = 0, margins = TRUE)
```

> ```
>    Retailer.country     E-mail        Fax      Mail Sales visit   Special  Telephone       Web     (all)
> 1         Australia   171407.3       0.00       0.0  2013909.18  158795.3  2289201.9   1738304   6371617
> 2           Austria        0.0       0.00       0.0    66926.18       0.0  1671887.4   7050164   8788978
> 3           Belgium        0.0       0.00       0.0  1655507.05       0.0        0.0   6222440   7877947
> 4            Brazil        0.0       0.00       0.0        0.00       0.0        0.0   7746790   7746790
> 5            Canada  6864270.1  195549.50       0.0   450628.79       0.0        0.0  12376529  19886977
> 6             China        0.0  415128.31       0.0  1453194.14       0.0  2735416.3  15777880  20381619
> 7           Denmark        0.0       0.00       0.0   413978.16       0.0        0.0   3776833   4190811
> 8           Finland        0.0       0.00       0.0   308638.60       0.0        0.0  12328173  12636812
> 9            France        0.0  709194.65       0.0  1304167.86       0.0  5897377.1  11048161  18958901
> 10          Germany  1546079.4       0.00 1247170.1  2373591.15       0.0        0.0  12102241  17269082
> 11            Italy  2461322.5  165800.42       0.0  1397604.56  198705.0        0.0   7413834  11637266
> 12            Japan  2662351.9  289704.50  680467.9    87186.72  343708.9  1802166.7  16990818  22856404
> 13            Korea        0.0       0.00       0.0  2821127.32       0.0   431860.3  10144354  13397341
> 14           Mexico        0.0       0.00       0.0  5063353.42 1725508.5        0.0   3571761  10360623
> 15      Netherlands        0.0  593828.88 1074860.7        0.00       0.0  2981026.9   5254138   9903854
> 16        Singapore        0.0  469627.61       0.0        0.00  908725.1  1625096.6   9677070  12680519
> 17            Spain        0.0   88788.41  337710.7        0.00       0.0   254360.2   7835117   8515977
> 18           Sweden  1292812.4       0.00       0.0        0.00       0.0        0.0   4818849   6111661
> 19      Switzerland        0.0  217936.39       0.0   792168.42  790344.3   109161.0   4565897   6475507
> 20   United Kingdom   697619.3  264500.20       0.0   189218.02       0.0  2022969.0  13756025  16930332
> 21    United States        0.0 1357389.56 2352483.3  2842600.85  685752.2 13437403.3  29573814  50249443
> 22            (all) 15695863.0 4767448.43 5692692.6 23233800.42 4811539.3 35257926.7 203769190 293228461
> ```

Of course, `fun.aggregate` has to be specified as well.

---

The same functionality is also available from the `reshape2` package, the successor of `reshape`, but about 4 times faster for this small sample size.

```
reshape2::dcast(sales.by.country, Retailer.country ~ Order.method.type, fun.aggregate = sum, 
                fill = 0, margins = TRUE)
```

---

`dcast()` is also available from the `data.table` package which claims to be faster than `reshape2::dcast()`. Unfortunately, the `margins` parameter hasn't been implemented yet (current CRAN version 1.10.4). Therefore, the margins have to be computed separately and combined with the original data:

```
DT2 <- rbind(
  DT,
  DT[, .(Qtr.Rev = sum(Qtr.Rev)), by = Retailer.country],
  DT[, .(Qtr.Rev = sum(Qtr.Rev)), by = Order.method.type],
  DT[, .(Qtr.Rev = sum(Qtr.Rev))], 
  fill = TRUE
)
dcast(DT2, Retailer.country ~ Order.method.type, fill = 0)
```

> ```
>     Retailer.country     E-mail        Fax      Mail Sales visit   Special  Telephone       Web        NA
>  1:        Australia   171407.3       0.00       0.0  2013909.18  158795.3  2289201.9   1738304   6371617
>  2:          Austria        0.0       0.00       0.0    66926.18       0.0  1671887.4   7050164   8788978
>  3:          Belgium        0.0       0.00       0.0  1655507.05       0.0        0.0   6222440   7877947
>  4:           Brazil        0.0       0.00       0.0        0.00       0.0        0.0   7746790   7746790
>  5:           Canada  6864270.1  195549.50       0.0   450628.79       0.0        0.0  12376529  19886977
>  6:            China        0.0  415128.31       0.0  1453194.14       0.0  2735416.3  15777880  20381619
>  7:          Denmark        0.0       0.00       0.0   413978.16       0.0        0.0   3776833   4190811
>  8:          Finland        0.0       0.00       0.0   308638.60       0.0        0.0  12328173  12636812
>  9:           France        0.0  709194.65       0.0  1304167.86       0.0  5897377.1  11048161  18958901
> 10:          Germany  1546079.4       0.00 1247170.1  2373591.15       0.0        0.0  12102241  17269082
> 11:            Italy  2461322.5  165800.42       0.0  1397604.56  198705.0        0.0   7413834  11637266
> 12:            Japan  2662351.9  289704.50  680467.9    87186.72  343708.9  1802166.7  16990818  22856404
> 13:            Korea        0.0       0.00       0.0  2821127.32       0.0   431860.3  10144354  13397341
> 14:           Mexico        0.0       0.00       0.0  5063353.42 1725508.5        0.0   3571761  10360623
> 15:      Netherlands        0.0  593828.88 1074860.7        0.00       0.0  2981026.9   5254138   9903854
> 16:        Singapore        0.0  469627.61       0.0        0.00  908725.1  1625096.6   9677070  12680519
> 17:            Spain        0.0   88788.41  337710.7        0.00       0.0   254360.2   7835117   8515977
> 18:           Sweden  1292812.4       0.00       0.0        0.00       0.0        0.0   4818849   6111661
> 19:      Switzerland        0.0  217936.39       0.0   792168.42  790344.3   109161.0   4565897   6475507
> 20:   United Kingdom   697619.3  264500.20       0.0   189218.02       0.0  2022969.0  13756025  16930332
> 21:    United States        0.0 1357389.56 2352483.3  2842600.85  685752.2 13437403.3  29573814  50249443
> 22:               NA 15695863.0 4767448.43 5692692.6 23233800.42 4811539.3 35257926.7 203769190 293228461
>     Retailer.country     E-mail        Fax      Mail Sales visit   Special  Telephone       Web        NA
> ```

Comment: Excellent, that method makes this process much faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution using functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. `dt4` is the final output. Notice the use of `summarise_if`. It is useful when we only want to apply a function for columns that fit a pre-determined condition. In this case, we can apply the `sum` function only to columns that are numeric.

```
# Create example data frame
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# sales.by.country is created by OP's dput dataset
dt2 <- sales.by.country %>% 
  mutate(Retailer.country = as.character(Retailer.country)) %>%
  # Spread the data frame
  spread(Order.method.type, Qtr.Rev, fill = 0) %>%
  # Calcualte Total.cn by rowSums
  mutate(TOTAL.cn = rowSums(.[, 2:ncol(.)])) 

# Calculate the sum of each column if it is numeric
dt3 <- dt2 %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, sum)

# Combine dt3 (the summary) to dt2
dt4 <- dt2 %>%
  bind_rows(dt3) %>%
  # Replace the na in Retailer.country to be "TOTAL.type"
  replace_na(list(Retailer.country = "TOTAL.type"))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when attempting to declare dt2:
`Error: incompatible size (21), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1`

Comment: @RVD Are you talking about the dt I created based on your example or your actual dataset?

Comment: I took my original data and saved it in a similar format before running your code. To keep this process reproducible, I just took your code above and pasted it into a new script. dt and dt2 are created without any issue. When I try to initialize dt3, I'm getting this error: `Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: Sales visit
          ^`

Comment: @RVD You saw this error because in your original `sales.by.country` the `Retailer.country` column is factor, while when I created my example dataset, `dt`, the `Retailer.country` column is character. I have updated my answer, adding `mutate(Retailer.country = as.character(Retailer.country))` in the process to create `dt2`. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Yep, got it to work! I had to change the 5th column name of dt2 to "sales.visit" (instead of "sales visit") before running the dt3 line. Otherwise, it throws the same parse error I posted earlier. After that, dt4 works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `tidyr` to spread and `janitor` to add totals column & row:

```
library(janitor)
library(tidyr)
sales.by.country %>%
  spread(Order.method.type, Qtr.Rev, fill = 0) %>%
  adorn_totals(c("row", "col"))
```