# How to display data `str()` without attributes

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to show the data structure of a dataframe/Tibble BUT Without the attributes `- attr(*, "spec")=` at the end. Is there another command (or better way) that shows only lines 2 & 3?

```
## spec_tbl_df [4,238 × 2] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
##  $ male           : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
##  $ age            : num [1:4238] 39 46 48 61 46 43 63 45 52 43 ...
##  - attr(*, "spec")=
##   .. cols(
##   ..   male = col_factor(levels = c("0", "1"), ordered = FALSE, include_na = FALSE),
##   ..   age = col_double(),
##   .. )
##  - attr(*, "problems")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Related post, possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24996330/680068

Comment: And many other ways on this r-faq: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `dplyr::glimpse(df)` might be helpful too

Comment: @zx8754 I agree that your links are helpful but they do not address this issue specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `give.attr=FALSE`. *Example:*

```
test <- `attr<-`(data.frame(), 'foo', 'bar')

str(test)
# 'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
# - attr(*, "foo")= chr "bar"

str(test, give.attr=FALSE)
# 'data.frame': 0 obs. of  0 variables
```